# Запуск SQL скрипта перед стартом asp.net core приложения

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Есть приложение asp.net core, которое общается с MSSQL базой с помощью dapper. Есть скрипт удаления и создания базы с тестовыми данными. Нужно каким-то образом сделать так чтобы скрипт срабатывал при сборке приложения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо в `.csproj` файл нужного проекта добавить [target](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets), который будет выполняется перед сборкой:

```
<Target BeforeTargets="Build" Name="ExecuteSQL">
  <Message Text="------------------------" />
  <Message Text="-------ExecuteSQL-------" />
  <Message Text="------------------------" />
  <Exec Command="$(comspec) /k powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -File .\sql.ps1" />
</Target>
```

Данный `target` запускает скрипт на `PowerShell`, который в свою очередь будет выполнять запрос к базе данных:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile ".\MyScript.sql"
```

или

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "DROP DATABASE MyDatabase"
```

В реальном сценарии для работы понадобиться передать в команду параметры вроде: `Server`, `Database`, `Username`, `Password`.

---

[Build Target Map](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/wiki/Target-Maps.md) | [COMSPEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMSPEC) | [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)